# Adding non-cObject data (custom class) into a packet in Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, inet

I am trying to create a packet and attach a custom object. I read through the manual and tried following their suggestions but I am stuck.

According to the manual: Non-cObject data can be attached to messages by wrapping them into cObject, for example into cMsgPar which has been designed expressly for this purpose.

cMsgPar has the function: setObjectValue(), so I attempted to add the class via this code:

```
// b is a pointer to a custom object
    auto packet = createPacket("Msg");

    packet->addPar("data");
    packet->par("data").setObjectValue(b);
```

but I get a 'no matching function for call' error for the setObject value function. I checked the function declaration, which is:

```
cMsgPar &   setObjectValue (cOwnedObject *obj)
```

which brings me back to square one. Trying to convert my custom class into something acceptable by Omnet to send to other nodes in my network.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way of carrying own classes (objects) via message in OMNeT++ is to add this to definition of a message. For example:

```
cplusplus {{
#include "MyClass.h"  // assuming that MyClass is declared here 
typedef MyClass *MyClassPtr;
}};

class noncobject MyClassPtr;

packet MyPacket {
    int x;
    MyClassPtr ptr;
}
```

Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual - 6.6 Using C++ Types](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msg-defs:using-cpp-types)

Comment: I am getting a few errors when using the MSGC compiler. Should this work for this version?

Comment: I suggest opening a new question for this problem including [mcve] as well as version of OMNeT++ you use.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it as an easy solution. Omnet++ already gave alot of ways to do it.

```
msg->addPar("preamble");
msg->par("preamble").setLongValue(0b01010101010101);
send(msg,"phyout");
```

i hope it will helpout